# .htaccess rewrite url [apache]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite an url with .htaccess and do a 301 redirect to it.

The original url is like this **http://localhost/labs/customer_132/?kund=goteborg-stad**

I want it to look like this and redirect it to

**http://localhost/labs/customer_132/?page_id=11#goteborg-stad**

Tried diffrent solutions but i dont get the hang of it.

**Thank you for all your help!**

Comment: `page_id=11` is not even there in your original URI?

Comment: Yeah i know what the last part of the string to "stay" and change the part behinde that. Its an ajax page change with Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the query string directly using a `RewriteRule` stament; instead you need a preceding `RewriteCond` that checks there is a `kund` field and captures its value. Then you can use `%N` in the `RewriteRule` to use any captured values.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} kund=([\w\-]+)
RewriteRule ^/labs/customer_132/ /labs/customer_132/?page_id=11#%1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin, will try that! get back if it dont work :)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to turn the Rewrite engine on in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then, for a single URL redirect the following should work (if the .htaccess file is in the root folder or the server).

**Edit:** you need to check the query string condition this will match if the query string is exactly `kund=goteborg-stad` (in upper or lower case).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^kund=goteborg-stad$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^labs\/customer_132\/$ /labs/customer_132/?page_id=11#goteborg-stad [NE,R,L]
```

The `NE` tells Apache not to escape the `#` symbol in the redirect.

If you want to redirect a selection of different URLs (eg. will the customer ID change?) then you need to clarify.

Comment: -1: a `RewriteRule` like that will *never* match as the query string is removed from the URL before `RewriteRule` sees it.

Comment: Sorry I was being stupid. Use %{QUERY_STRING} to look at the query. Then redirect as usual but make sure you include `[NE]` so the hash is not encoded to `%23` as in your answer.
I haven't used the `kund` query as the fragment as it was unclear as to whether this was needed as they would all still redirect to same `page_id`.